# Check if element exists in list of tuples

Tags: python

I have this list of tuples:

```
db_content = [('014f2e5b80683d91dfea2c9159',), ('17675e415e05ed1100468d162d3',), ('19bc7d0146fd004bf090db94e50',)
```

The following code doesn't return true. Why?

```
print('014f2e5b80683d91dfea2c9159' in db_content)
```

Comment: Tuple is a collection itself, try for example `print(['014f2e5b80683d91dfea2c9159' in entry for entry in db_content])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a tuple containing a string is not equal to the string.

```
print ('014f2e5b80683d91dfea2c9159' == ('014f2e5b80683d91dfea2c9159',))
```

prints `False`.

If the tuples are all just one element, you can test for the tuple:

```
print(('014f2e5b80683d91dfea2c9159',) in db_content)
```

Comment: It works!
But what if some tuples contain more than one element?

Answer (score 3):

if you only want to know if the string is anywhere in the list of tuples, this line does the job:

```
print(any(['014f2e5b80683d91dfea2c9159' in tup for tup in db_content]))
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you have declared the strings values in tuples thus when you have called the string you got false result. if you only call the tuple not the string, you will get the output as true.
Try this:

```
print(('014f2e5b80683d91dfea2c9159',) in db_content)
```

Answer (score -1):

The code doesn't return true because you have put a `,` at the end of each element in your tuple.
Remove them and then your code may work.

Comment: I suspect the list of tuples is coming from somewhere else, not a literal.